# How to get controller of scene in JavaFx8?

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I use several scenes and currently there are one method for each scene, like

```
  void setScene1() {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/main2.fxml"));
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    loader.<Controller1>getController().callMethod();
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);

  }
```

but I want to remember Scene and do it like that

```
  void setScene1() {
    FXMLLoader loader = scene1.getLoaderSomehow(); // < ---- ????
    loader.<Controller1>getController().callMethod();
    primaryStage.setScene(scene1);

  }
```

Comment: imo, you just want to keep a reference of each controller to call a method ?

Comment: Just have a `static MyController ctrl` in the controller itself and in the controller's `initialize` functoin set `ctrl = this`, then you can easily access the controller from anywhere using `MyController.ctrl` object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This could be done using [`Scene.getUserData` and `Scene.setUserData`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html#setUserData-java.lang.Object-):

```
...
Scene scene = new Scene(root);
scene.setUserData(loader);
```

```
FXMLLoader loader = (FXMLLoader) scene.getUserData();
```

But you should keep the following in mind:

- You use the loader only to get the controller. The loader could contain references to objects that could be garbage collected otherwise. Consider keeping a reference to the controller instead.
- Any other place would be more convenient (and depending on the approach more typesafe). You're *"remembering"* the `Scene`, so why not *"remember"* the loader/controller too?

Answer (score 3):

To get the things more organised, you may create a new class that contains all necessary objects together:

```
// application screen i.e. view, "page"
public class AppScreen
{
    private String fxmlPath;
    private javafx.scene.Scene scene;
    private RootController rootController;

    // Getters, setters
}

// Collection to store loaded app screens, uses fxml path text as a key
private final Map<String, AppScreen> appScreens = new HashMap<>();

// load the fxml if it is not loaded previously or use already loaded one
void loadAppScreen( String fxmlPath ) throws IOException
{
    AppScreen appScreen;
    if ( appScreens.containsKey( fxmlPath ) )
    {
        appScreen = appScreens.get( fxmlPath );
    }
    else
    {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader( getClass().getResource( fxmlPath ) );
        Parent root = loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene( root );
        RootController rc = loader.<RootController>getController();

        appScreen = new AppScreen();
        appScreen.setFxmlPath( fxmlPath );
        appScreen.setScene( scene );
        appScreen.setRootController( rc );

        appScreens.put( fxmlPath, appScreen );
    }

    appScreen.getRootController().refreshData();
    primaryStage.setScene( appScreen.getScene() );
}
```